# Trouble making a list of commits with axios.get()

Tags: javascript, git, asynchronous, promise, axios

I'm trying to retrieve a list of commits within a repository using the Github API. After retrieving this list, I want to assign it to a list variable that I defined.

The reason why I want to do this is so I can extract information about the pull request, file(s) the commit is associated with, and the number of lines added/deleted from the file(s). I have the following code so far:

```
var listOfCommits = [];
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get(githubAPI).then(function (response) {
    listOfCommits = response['data'];
    console.log("in then part");
    console.log(listOfCommits[0]);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: something wrong happened");
}).finally(function () {
    console.log("hopefully this is done right...");
});

console.log("outside of the axios method");
console.log(listOfCommits[0]);
console.log("last debug");
```

I'm using Webstorm, so when I run the file using "node file.js" I get the following output:

> outside of the axios method
>   undefined
>   last debug
>   in then part
>   [stuff retrieved from the repository]
>   hopefully this is done right...

The variable `githubAPI` is a string that stores the URL needed for the API to retrieve the necessary information. The goal of this code is to assign the information retrieved to the variables `listOfCommits`. Inside the `axios.get()` method, `listOfCommits` is defined, but when I try printing it out again after the method, it's `undefined`.

I know that it has something to do with the fact that `axios.get()` returns a promise, but I'm not sure how to fix this as I'm not too familiar with Javascript. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense you're getting undefined. you're calling the data from outside the promise, you have no guarantee that the data will be ready at that time.

Comment: I know. But my question is, is there any way to make sure listOfCommits has the data outside of the promise so I can work with it? Or do I have to do everything within that promise, like getting the pull number and everything else I want to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
let listOfCommits = null;
(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get('')
    .then((resp) => {
        resolve(resp['data']);
      },
      error => {
        reject(error);
      }
    );
})
})()
.then((data)=> {
  listOfCommits = data;      
})
```

Comment: Would I have to work with listOfCommits after 

.then((data)=> {
  listOfCommits = data;   

Because I tried this and if I put a print statement console.log(listOfCommits[0]);
outside of this entire function, it still says it's undefined!

Comment: you should ask yourself whats going to happen with that listOfCommits... you might want to consider a 'more reactive' approach for your application.

Comment: The thing is that the axios call will be excecuted within another thread and won't be finished before hitting your console statement.